# getting error Error 503 Site temporarily unavailable when download MODX revolution live to localhost

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

I am using MODX revolution.When we download it from live server to localhost i am getting error on browser.
Error 503

Site temporarily unavailable

I have made changes in config file but still it is showing same error.Can Anyone suggest how can we solve this error
I have added directory path in :

```
  $modx_connectors_path
  $modx_manager_path
  $modx_base_path
  $http_host
  $modx_assets_path
```

Answer (score 1):

you also need to check &/or update your paths in /config.core.php, /manager/config.core.php & /connectors/config.core.php

depending on how you installed it, these may have absolute paths.

if you have moved your /core/ directory, these will need to be updated.

Also, clear out your cache directory.....

Answer (score 0):

https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/moving-your-site-to-a-new-server

In above example you have step by step tutorial. Remember to first clear cache and log-off all users (destroy all sessions), remove 'core/cache/' directory and then move all other files.

Also remember to move database and update it's username/password at core/config/config.inc.php file.

If you still have problems try to check your logs file (core/cache/logs/) or check WebServer logs (at localhost you should have access to them).